# How to regenerate DEVELOPER_ACCESS_TOKEN in DialogFlow?

Tags: access-token, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es, google-home

I have my agent hosted in DialogFlow. Because of security reasons, I need to update DEVELOPER_ACCESS_TOKEN. I know there is a way to update CLIENT_ACCESS_TOKEN from settings. But didn't find any way to update DEVELOPER_ACCESS_TOKEN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your developer access token is compromised, you should create a new agent and transfer your intents and entities across.

1. Create a new agent
2. [Export your current agent as a zip](https://dialogflow.com/docs/best-practices/import-export-for-versions)
3. [Import the zip](https://dialogflow.com/docs/best-practices/import-export-for-versions) to the new agent you created in step 1.

If you are using this Dialogflow agent with Actions on Google and wish to continue using the API V1, you will need to create a new Action.

Alternately, consider switching your agent to use the API V2 Beta, which uses [Google Cloud Service Accounts](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/v2-auth-setup) instead of API keys and will solve your problem.

Comment: Hi Dan! Thanks for your response! Is it official? I wonder what was the motivation to hide revoke functions for the developer access token. Do you know? it is usual functionality in other services but not in this one.

Comment: Hi Eugene! Yes, this is official, and I agree that this is a problem. In the V2 API (currently in beta, stable version coming soon) we've shifted to using Google Cloud service accounts for API auth, which both solves this problem and provides additional security. I updated my answer to include this. The doc page on V2 auth is here: https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/v2-auth-setup

Comment: Thank Dan for the response! Sadly current stable version of node.js SDK doesn't support v2, but I see you have an alpha version here https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-on-google-nodejs/tree/v2.0.0-alpha. We're developing https://github.com/internetarchive/internet-archive-google-action with media responses. Should we try to use it now, or it would be simpler to migrate to the new version. Once it will be at least in beta?

Comment: Exciting to see Internet Archive is coming to AoG! I would definitely recommend using V2 and the alpha AoG client library. In addition to the API changes, we've made a ton of improvements that make the library a lot more enjoyable to use. You can read a little about it here: https://medium.com/@silvano.luciani/actions-on-google-client-library-for-node-js-v2-0-0-alpha-c92361167f15